# Custom framework crashes in iPhone 6 devices due to NFC feature even though CoreNFC framework set to optional in Link binary with libraries

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, nfc, core-nfc

I have integrated Core NFC inside my iOS framework and used in demo app... Demo app works fine when ran in devices above iPhone 7, but crashing in devices less than iPhone 6 which doesn't support NFC. And Also CoreNFC framework set to optional in  **Link binary with libraries under Build Phases**

**NOTE: I am using CoreNFC inside my custom framework**

Below is the error thrown when running the app in iPhone 6

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreNFC.framework/CoreNFC
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/32DFDD02-36AA-425D-9EC2-8D2DB148309F/DEMOApp.app/Frameworks/CustomFramework.framework/CustomFramework
  Reason: image not found

Could any one please let me know how to handle Core NFC inside a framework for devices below iPhone 6(Which are NON NFC compatible)

Comment: Did u find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.You need to handle the CoreNFC.framework as optional inside your custom framework like mentioned in the below picture.

[image]

Also don't forget to provide Privacy permission string in the info.plist file of your framework hosting app.

[image]